# Defining a regex for two characters then two numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a regex in my React app to validate the input of the form entry. The input uses an onChange listener to call a function which sets the state on character change.

A valid input is two characters followed by two digits. i.e RD01 or EX12

I have it plumbed up with the re working. It matches for the correct case although it also works for just two digits. i.e. 01 or 12

```js
    const onAssetChange = (e) => {
        const input = e.target.value.toUpperCase()
        const re = new RegExp('^[A-Z]{0,2}[0-9]{0,2}$')
        if (!input || input.match(re)) {
            setAssetID(input)
        }
    }
```

The regex needs to be able to update on each key stroke as it updates state on each change event.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The quantifers should be `{2}` to match 2 times. `{0,2}` Matches 0, 1 or 2 times.

Comment: "The regex needs to be able to update on each key string as it updates state on each change." - If the intermediate result aren't also valid like the end result, you need a different regex check for your end result. I'd recommend checking only the end result and providing an example in a tooltip, watermark or something.

Comment: @Croc Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it isn't pretty...

```js
    const onAssetChange = (e) => {
        const input = e.target.value.toUpperCase()
        const re = new RegExp('^[A-Z]{0,2}[0-9]{0,2}$')
        if (!input || input.match(re) && (input.length < 2 ? input[0].match(/[A-Z]/) : input.slice(0,2).match(/[A-Z][A-Z]/)) ) {
            setAssetID(input)
        }
    }
```

but it works. If anyone has a more elegant solution I'm interested to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}` regex.

The mistake in your regex was `{0,2}` quantifier matches for 0 to 2 elements in the provided charset. Use `{2}` instead. This will assert to check for exactly 2 count of charset.

What my suggestion is to use a mockFunction to update your input to tme required standard like mapping `HI as HI00`, `AA as AA00`, `Aa as Aa00` etc and test this mocked string. This is a sample for the same.

```js
console.log('R -- ', mockInput('R'));
console.log('RD --', mockInput('RD'));
console.log('RD0 -- ', mockInput('RD0'));
console.log('RD01 -- ', mockInput('RD01'));
console.log('01 -- ', mockInput('01'));
console.log('R01 -- ', mockInput('R01'));
console.log('RD011 -- ', mockInput('RD011'));

function mockInput(input) {
  const returnStr = "AA00";
  const fakeInput = input.length >= 4? input: input + returnStr.substring(input.length, 4);
  const re = RegExp(/[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}/);
  let status = false;
  if (re.test(fakeInput)) {
    status = true;
  }
  return status;
};
```

Comment: I missed an importand piece of information which I have added to the question. It needs to be able to be updated per key stroke. In this case, only works if the whole case is added then submitted.

Comment: Could you please clarify the requirement with an example?

Comment: R = valid
RD = valid
RD0 = valid
RD01 = valid
01 = invalid
R01 = invalid
RD011 = invalid

Comment: @Croc I need to check whether this could be achieved with simple regex.

Answer (score 0):

`RegExp('^[A-Z]{0,2}[0-9]{0,2}$')` will check for either `0`,`1` or `2` characters. The same would do for the numbers so even `A1` would be a valid one. Try the following:

```
const re = new RegExp('^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}$')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `'^[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9]$'`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
const onAssetChange = (e) => {
    const input = e.target.value.toUpperCase()
    const re = new RegExp('^\w{2}\d{2}$')
    if (!input || input.match(re)) {
        setAssetID(input)
    }
}
```